# Пренаправления при html5Mode

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, angularjs

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

На локальном сервере, так что не обращайте внимания на домен.
Всё нормально работает для урлов такого вида 
http://quest/abouts

В таких урлах не пашет перенаправление

```
http://quest/item/1
http://quest/item/2
http://quest/item/3
```

Как собственно настроить?

PS

```
 when('/item/:questId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/quests/quest.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
```

Мод

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('#');
```

Ещё потестил работает вот так, без слеша, в общем его как то настроить нужно

```
when('/item:test', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/quests/quest.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
 console.log($routeParams.test)
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что вот это `RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]` допустимое правило? Может надо что-то вроде `RewriteRule .* index.html [L]`?

Comment: да так сработало =) но при перезагрузке страницы не пашет стили погружаются как то так "http://quest/quest/css/style.css". а должны "http://quest/css/style.css". урл http://quest/quest/4 вместо первого quest будет домен

Comment: ага, похоже потому что мапится вообще вся строка, а если так: `RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} index.html [L]`?

Comment: http://samquest.net/ тут тоже самое только на nginx, если перейти на прямую не подгружает стили http://samquest.net/quest/5

Comment: вроде разобрался, не везде слеши поставил при подключении библиотек, кажется из-за этого